# How to duplicate a line and then comment the 1st occurrence

Tags: text-processing, string

I would like to duplicate a line and comment one of the occurrences. This is more like keeping a copy before I make changes to the copied line (uncommented one).

Input File :

```
Hi , can you help me here?
```

Output FIle:

```
#Hi , can you help me here?
Hi , can you help me here?
```

Comment: Do you need to programmatically do this to many files? Do you know what each line that needs to be copied starts and ends with? If you do not need to do this via a script, what text editor are you using? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/543476/edit) your post to include these details. Thank you.

Comment: Is there something you already tried? Why it failed? I mean you should include a bit more information and try to solve it on your own as well.

Answer (score 5):

With `sed`, for every line of the file:

```
sed 'h;s/^/#/p;g' < input-file > output-file
```

Same with `awk`:

```
awk '{print "#" $0 ORS $0}' < input-file > output-file
```

Or with `paste`:

```
paste -d '#\n' /dev/null input-file input-file > output-file
```

If `input-file` contains:

```
foo
bar
```

That will result in:

```
#foo
foo
#bar
bar
```

If you'd rather see

```
#foo
#bar
foo
bar
```

then you could do:

```
paste -d'#' /dev/null input-file | cat - input-file > output-file
```

Comment: I was about to suggest `h;s/^/#/;G` - is there a reason (such as portability) to prefer `p;g` over `G` here?

Comment: @steeldriver, not really other than it makes it less likely to reach the limit of the length of the pattern space.

Comment: Ah gotcha - thanks

Comment: tis works but i need one addl change..

Comment: I would like to comment only the Lines that start with a , say , "$AB"

Comment: Rewriting my adl. requirement again.. => I would like to COMMETN & DUPLICATE only the Lines that start with a starting string, say , "$AB"

Comment: @veekay, those requirements are not mentioned in your question.  Have you tried learning `sed` to solve your requirements yourself? https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: looks fine and works for me..

Answer (score 0):

For all lines do this :

```
$ sed -e 'h;G;s/^/#/' file


$ perl -pe '$_ = "#$_$_"' file
```

Constrain on specific lines :

```
$ sed -e 'h;s/^\$AB/#&/p;g' file

$ perl -pe 's/^(\$AB.*)/#$1$1/s' file
```

Comment: works for me fine